# maatwebsite/excel Import using chunks seems to be not working - Laravel 5.4

Tags: excel, laravel, phpexcel

I am following as per the documentation and queue executes fine, but no data after 1st are not stored in to database (for code sample, I am writing a separate files). Please refer my code below.

Package version: 2.1.0
Laravel version: 5.4.36

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load(storage_path('users.csv'))->
chunk(250,function($results){
       $row_set = $results->toArray();
       foreach ($row_set as $key => $row) {
           Storage::disk('local')->put(rand(10, 100).'_users.txt', json_encode($row));
       }
});
```

Configurations:
php.ini -> auto_detect_line_endings : true
export.php
force_sheets_collection: true,
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

Please help me to resolve this issue and I spend around 2 days to find a solution in different bug reports and solutions.

Comment: Nothing in this code stores anything in a database.

Comment: (You're also going to be overwriting data, as `rand(10, 100)` only has 90 possibilities. Even a single chunk of 250 items is going to obliterate most of itself, let alone the *next* chunk. Ditch this code and start over entirely...)

Comment: @ceejayoz instead of storing the data in dab, am writing to a file for demonstrating the code. I tried to change values from 100 to 10000 but there is no result. `$row_set` is empty from the second time of queue on wards.

Comment: What is "queue on wards"? Does your CSV have more than 250 rows?

Comment: Yes, file contain around 1000 rows

Answer (score 1):

You should set your $results into function, also you need to make sure by placing Log::debug() messages in you foreach loop

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load(storage_path('users.csv'))->
chunk(250,function($results){
       foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
           Storage::disk('local')->put(rand(10, 100).'_users.txt', json_encode($row));
       }
});
```

Comment: did you check how many records in your CSV ? also did you put Log in your foreach loop?